# Layout viewport css width attribute

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, viewport

I read this article [A tale of two viewports](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html)

In this article the author writes:

"the CSS layout, especially percentual widths, are calculated relative to the layout viewport"

"The point is: browsers have chosen their dimensions of the layout viewport such that it completely covers the screen in fully zoomed-out mode (and is thus equal to the visual viewport)."

I do not understand the following paragraph :

"Now what you could try is setting html {width: 320px}. Now the  element shrinks, and with it all other elements, which now take 100% of 320px. This works when the user zooms in, but not initially, when the user is confronted with a zoomed-out page that mostly contains nothing"

**If the screen size of device is around 320 pixels so is the  layout viewport and if the css width for the html element is  set to  320px  why does  element shrinks ?**

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If the screen size of device is around 320 pixels so is the layout viewport and if the css width for the html element is set to 320px why does element shrinks ?

you have a default viewport of ca 980px on your mobile device, **if you do not reset it** with the meta-tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` (or any addition to that).

A mobile browser auto scales your page so the size of 980px fits the screen, making your 320px only a third of that.

Comment: Thank you for your good answer. So the following : "the CSS layout, especially percentual widths, are calculated relative to the layout viewport" relate to original layout viewport (980px)and not to the new one of 320px : Am I right ? (zoom affects only the visual viewport)

Comment: erm, yes. it is recommended to adjust the viewport to the device-width to prevent glitches. but if you do adjust the viewport, thats the viewport that is used for calculations.

Comment: Thank you.What was confusing in the article for me was : "browsers have chosen their dimensions of the layout viewport such that is equal to the  the visual viewport"   Layout viewport not supposed to change once they are determined .I have thought that CSS width is compered against this initial fixed value of 320px of Layout viewport.